# execute plugin task after my task

Tags: gradle

I've got plugin task with name for example `name1`.
And I've got my task `task1`.

When I execute task `name1` I want to execute my `task1`.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `dependsOn` or `mustRunAfter`. [Link](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html) to the docs.

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your `build.gradle`:

```
name1.dependsOn(task1)
```